# SEGFAULT Getting Results Using MySQL/C++ Connector

Tags: c++, mysql, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to display a small MySQL table via C++ using the MySQL/C++ Connector, but when I execute the following function, my program either quits with the message "Aborted" or I get a segfault. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I thought I followed the documentation pretty well. :/

```
void
addressBook::display(sql::Connection* con)
{
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;

    // Create the statement object
    stmt = con->createStatement();

    // Execute a query and store the result in res
    res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM address_book "
                 "ORDER BY last_name, first_name");

    // Loop through the results and display them
    if(res)
    {
        while(res->next())
        {
            std::cout << "Name: " << res->getString("first_name")
                  << " "    << res->getString("last_name") << std::endl
                  << "Phone: " << res->getString("phone") << std::endl
                  << "eMail: " << res->getString("email") << std::endl
                  << "City: " << res->getString("city") << std::endl
                  << "Comments: " << res->getString("comments")
                  << std::endl << std::endl;
        }
    }
    delete stmt;
    delete res;
}
```

The full (as of yet, unfinished) program may be found here, for reference. http://pastebin.com/kWnknHi4

Also, each field in the table being called contains a valid string.

**Edit** The debugger message can be found here: http://pastebin.com/NnSqV8hv

Comment: what does your debugger say? What line number does it tell you?

Comment: That's not a debugger.  It's glibc; specifically, it's detecting that your program is passing an invalid pointer to `free`.  Even though you don't call `free` directly, a library that you're using is.  The GNU debugger is `gdb`.  There are various programs that wrap `gdb`, including Emacs, Eclipse, and NetBeans.

Comment: Sorry, the backtrace info is here: http://pastebin.com/1wp1e5te

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the libraries were installed incorrectly on my system; according to the docs, you run `make clean` as an intermediary step, when it should just be `make`.

Thanks to vinleod from ##c++-basic (Vincent Damewood of http://damewood.us/) for the help in figuring that out.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're calling `delete` in the wrong order.  The [example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html) deletes `res` first.

The `ResultSet` destructor may reference the associated `Statement`.

Generally, you should do `free`/`delete` in the opposite order you created/allocated the object.

Comment: I fixed that, but it didn't seem to do anything. :/